# Is there an extension of Twitter Bootstrap for Retina-Display?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, retina-display

Its a lot headache trying to merge bootstrap CSS and CSS specific to retina-display.

So is there an easy way to do this. May be someone has built an extension about it.

Answer (score 6):

There is one extension for images [Retina JS](http://retinajs.com/) . It check the server for higher quality image on server , if it exists , replacement is done . For more info you can visit the Link.

You can also use HTML5 boiler plate and combine it with bootstrap .

[HTML5 Mobile Boiler Plate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! Can you please clarify why you're recommending HTML5 boiler plate. It seems like Retina JS solves the issue entirely alone.

Comment: Wouldn't retina JS add to the server load time and page load with its http queries?

Comment: Yeah, retina.js downloads regular-sized images no matter what the display is. The solution is media queries (Retina.js has an `at2x()` compass mix-in).

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 3, there is the `img-retina` mixin.